# How to pass image from one page to other using PHP?

Tags: php, css

I have been trying to execute the code for long time but rest then my image all other variables are working. My images are stored in server folder called "uploaded".

I have two pages called "show.php" and "readmore.php", and I want to pass the image from show.php to readmore.php but other then image all the variables are displaying in readmore.php.

My code for show.php

```
<a class="btn" href="readmore.php?ad_title=<?php echo $rec['ad_title']; ?> & price= <?php echo $rec['price']; ?> & address= <?php echo $rec['address']; ?>  & phone= <?php echo $rec['m_number']; ?> & description= <?php echo $rec['description']; ?> & contact_name= <?php echo $rec['contact_name'] ; ?> & photo_name= <?php echo $rec['photo_name']?>;">
```

My code for readmore.php (I am displaying here two of the variables along with the image)

```
 <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">About the book</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                        <?php echo $_GET['description'];?>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                   <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">About the book</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                       <td id="pic" width="300px"><img src= "../uploaded/<?php echo $_GET['photo_name'];?>" style="border-radius:5px; padding:3px; "/></td>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: If you are getting description right, the image also should display. please check the path of the image. you can view the source of your generated html page to see the generated image path. you may find something wrong there.

Comment: Stupid question but does $_GET['photo_name'] have the file extension in it?

Comment: hey man insert the code for your show .php page

Comment: For future readers, there are two XSS vulnerabilities in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to debug:

On first lines of readmore.php dump the superglobal variable $_GET and see whether value of $_GET['photo_name'] is coming or not.

Eg.

```
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($_GET);
echo "</pre>";
```

P.S. `<pre>` tag is just for formatting the output. print_r dumps the values of $_GET.

If you see value of 'photo_name' index in the GET array, 
there should be some errors in your image path.